# mysql database how to store contact data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch contacts from phone
and store into mysql database
I have:--

User table

```
id,userId, name, username, password
```

Contact table

```
id
userId(foreignkey(from user table))
contact_name
mobileNo(unique-primary key)
email(unique key)
```

Now problem is:

1)Suppose I am fetching sonia's contact list
where,
she has one contact:-

```
Name  mobileNo     email
Soma 5675675675    aaa@mail.com
```

another user preeti's contact list has:-

```
Name  mobileNo     email
sree 999999385    aaa@mail.com
```

and again another user lila's contact list has:-

```
Name  mobileNo     email
mona 5675675675    agawasti@mail.com
```

In my database 
**mobileNo** and **email** is unique-primary key,
but for every user name/email/mobileNo may be different..how I can store and manage these data 
for individual user??

I got one solution :-

1] User_info Table

```
id | UserId | name | username |password
```

2] Contacts Table

```
ContactId | Contact_Name | Contact_Phno |Contact_Email
```

3] User_Contact Table

```
UserId | ContactId
```

but Here, in **Contacts** table how can I manage to store sonia,preeti/lila's contact information? because the values are different.

Comment: Store contact table value into same table using array and serialize .

Comment: So users are not allowed to change their personal details? Strange.

Comment: And don't store name in user table - or is it conceivable that a user has no corresponding contact row?

Comment: @Strawberry, name in user table and contact table is different..please read the question carefully...I want to store every users contact details

Comment: Please ask the question carefully. We don't know what a user.name is

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one primary key per table, but maybe you defined a composite key (can't tell from the question)? I would suggest making 'id' a primary key and to add uniqueness constraints on the mobileNo and email. This choice also plays nicely with most of the web-frameworks you might be using.

```
ALTER TABLE `contact` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`mobileNo`, `email`);
```

Comment: ok,But How can I store these valuse??because sonia and lila's ph no is same but name and email is different..so only one of their value will store...Is there any way to store their values?

Comment: If the phone number can be the same, why do you declare them as primary keys (these are unique by definition), in the contact table?

Comment: I think phNo & email is unique.i.e I put as primary key..So,If I change primary key to unique key then will it work?

Comment: You can make them a 'composed primary key', but most people would recommend making 'id' a primary key, and simply defining a composite uniqueness constraint on the phone number and email. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

check your data type for phone number. May be it is integer and your phone number is over its limit..